# Problemas com acentuação - Python

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8, cmd, console

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Olá, estou com problemas de acentuação no Python.

No código eu coloco o isto: # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
Mas os acentos não são reconhecidos no cmd.

Segue print para melhor entendimento.

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Teste a solução do @Miguel. Se não resolver, uma alternativa é você ao salvar o arquivo, no seu editor de código ou IDE, mudar a configuração para ANSI, ISO-8859-1, WIN1252 (no lugar do UTF-8 que aparece na barra de status do seu screenshot). Geralmente isso é uma opção ao escolher "salvar como...", ou mesmo dando 2 cliques ou botão direito no local apropriado da barra de status, dependendo do editor.

Answer (score 3):

[Quando tiver um tempinho, leia isso aqui](http://augustoberziner.blogspot.com/2010/04/o-minimo-absoluto-que-cada.html). O título pode assustar um pouco -mas é a melhor introdução a acentuação e caractéres especiais que já vi.

Dito isso, o que acontece é que: até uns 30 anos atrás, os computadores estavam limitados à exibir um máximo de 256 caractéres de cada vez. É facil perceber que com tantas línguas e caractéres no mundo, isso nem começa a dar conta das necessidades de comunicação que temos.

Bom, como paliativo, cada país adotou uma tabela *diferente* de 256 caractéres - preservando um núcleo comum de códigos entre 0 e 127 (esse é o chamad "ASCII"), e criando novos mapas para os códigos de 128 até 255.

Aliás, as tabelas difernetes não foram só por "país", mas diversas tabelas apareceram em momentos diferentes da história em vários países.
O consórcio Unicode eventualmente foi instituído - ele padroniza todas essas tabelas diferentes, dando a cada uma um nome - além de colocar padrões de codificação que suportam mais que 256 caractéres simultâneos - por exemplo o "utf-8".

No caso do Windows você tem um problema maior ainda por que programas no ambiente normal do Windows usam uma codificação (`latin1` para windows em Português), e programas rodando no CMD usam **outra** codificação diferente - (cp852).
Por isso, um caractére que apareça como 'È' num editor de programação pode aparecer como "╚" quando for impresso no CMD.

A linguagem Python, a partir da versão 3 melhora bastante a abordagem e simplifica a programação correta - em particular, ela trata automaticamente todo o texto no código como "texto unicode", que é independente da codificação (mas ainda assim, você tem que deixar a codificação do seu editor de programação igual a codificação demarcada na primeira linha do código Python) - e verifica automaticamente qual é a codificação do terminal quando encontra um `print` ou outra saída. Assim, seu caractére `È` vai aparecer certinho no cmd. Eu recomendo fortemente que você use Python3 se estiver aprednendo ou começando um projeto novo - essa questão da codificação de textos é a mais importante da mudança de versões. (A partir do seu print, eu suponho que você esteja usando Python 2 - justamente pelos caractéres que aparecem).

Para Python 2, faça assim:

1. configure seu editor para realmente usar UTF-8 nos menus, além da
   declaração de codificação na primeira linha do seu programa.
2. Prefixe todas as suas strings com a letra `u`, com em: `a = u"maçã"`  - isso fara com que elas sejam objetos do tipo "unicode" e não ssó uma sequência de bytes. (esse é o comportamento padrão do Python3)
3. Em cada print, codifique o seu texto para a codificação padrão do terminal, chamando o método `.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)` no seu texto. (importe o módulo sys no seu programa). Esse comportamento também é padrão no Python3.

Exemplo em Python2:

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys

coding = sys.stdout.encoding
a = "eu tenho uma maçã"
print a.encode(coding)
```

Exemplo em Python3 (desde que o seu editor esteja configurado para utf-8):

```
print("Eu tenho uma maçã")
```

(não é necessária nem mesmo a declaração de codificação no próprio arquivo .py, quando esta for utf-8)